# Kotlin flow exception handling with buffer()

Tags: kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a simple flow that throws exception on second element:

```
private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test")

fun main() = runBlocking {
    flowOf(1, 2, 3)
        .onCompletion { log.info("Flow completed${if (it == null) "" else " exceptionally: ${it.message}"}") }
        .buffer()
        .map { throwingMapper(it) }
        .catch { log.error("Exception thrown") }
        .collect { log.info(it) }
    }
}

fun throwingMapper(it: Int): String {
    if (it == 2) {
        throw Exception("Test exception")
    }
    return "$it-mapped"
}
```

When I execute this code, I get the following output - the flow is completed **without exception**:

```
2021-04-09 12:35:00.875 [main] INFO  - test:31 - Flow completed
2021-04-09 12:35:00.904 [main] INFO  - test:133 - 1-mapped
2021-04-09 12:35:00.915 [main] ERROR - test:34 - Exception thrown
```

However, when I move the `map` operator before `buffer`:

```
flowOf(1, 2, 3)
        .onCompletion { log.info("Flow completed${if (it == null) "" else " exceptionally: ${it.message}"}") }
        .map { throwingMapper(it) }
        .buffer()
        .catch { log.error("Exception thrown") }
        .collect { log.info(it) }
```

the following output is produced and the flow is completed **with the exception**:

```
2021-04-09 12:38:35.982 [main] INFO  - test:31 - Flow completed exceptionally: Test exception
2021-04-09 12:38:36.024 [main] ERROR - test:34 - Exception thrown
```

How come the flow is completed unexceptionally in the first case? Does `buffer` silently swallow the downstream exception? Or does it internally create a new flow? If so, is there some was to retain the original exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html) for this method states:

> The `buffer` operator creates a separate coroutine during execution for the flow it applies to.
> [...]
> Code before `buffer` will be executed in a separate new coroutine [...] concurrently with [coroutine that calls this code].

Flow completed unexceptionally in the first case because method throwing exception and method catching it were both placed on one side of `buffer`, so they were executed in the same coroutine.

> A channel is used between the coroutines to send elements emitted by the coroutine P to the coroutine Q.

I don't think it's possible to send an exception via `Channel`, so you may need to define two `catch` handlers - before and after `buffer` (if you expect exceptions to be thrown in both parts).

Comment: I see, thank you! But given the exception is only ever thrown in the second part of the flow (after buffer), there is no way to "propagate it" (i.e. mark the flow as completed exceptionally) to the first part?

Comment: Channel between the coroutines is one-way. If you need to deal with exception thrown in the second part, then you should put `onCompletion` handler after `buffer` as well (but before `catch`).